# How to add and remove a class from a single element with one click…

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I’m trying to trigger a complete CSS3 animation with a single click on an anchor element. My current version is working (based on lots of searching here and on Google), but it requires two clickable elements to be present.

Here’s what I have so far:

http://codepen.io/ProfessorSamoff/pen/rVNOdv

As you’ll see, the jQuery is pretty typical:

```
$('a.puff').click(function() {
    $('a.puff').addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

I know that I’m probably missing something pretty simple, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why are you adding and immediately removing a class?

Comment: It looks like your trying to make it do the strange shake effect when you click one of the links, but it's currently doing it on the other link than the one you clicked??  If so, swap your addClass and removeClass on the objects.

Comment: So.... You're adding a class to every other a.puff and then removing the class from the one which was clicked, hence not playing the animation on the targeted a.puff...? $(this).addClass('active'); ? But I believe your actual issue is that you need to remove the class on CSS animation complete. so > http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end

Comment: To clarify, I’d like to be able to trigger this effect per link without having to click on another link to remove the class again. For instance, I’d like to be able to click a single link over and over again and watch the animation play every time.

Comment: You could add a setTimeout() for 150ms (to match your puff animation) that the removes the class from the element it was added to.

Comment: try the link that @Zze has given. it will help. see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dw3e5uky/

Comment: @Zze, thanks. I’ll look into the animationend idea.

Comment: @Sushil, thanks. Unfortunately, the JSFiddle version isn’t working.

Comment: The fiddle works for me :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS alone doesn't provide a mechanism to act on a keyframe animation/transition end, however it does fire a javascript-detectible event, as explained [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end).

Your repeatable puff animation will look like this :

```
$('a.puff').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-puff', $(this).text());
}).on('click', function() {
    var $a = $(this).addClass('active').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
        $a.removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

As far as I'm aware this is as simple as you can make it.

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qbwror)

Comment: All right! Thank you… And, thanks again to @Zze for this advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.puff').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('data-puff', $(this).text());
   });
   $('a.puff').click(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.addClass('active');
      setTimeout(function(){ $this.removeClass('active'); }, 150);
   });
});
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid setting a timer for something as simple as this — heck, I’d like to do it all in CSS3! So, this was a "last resort" option for me. Thanks, though!